# DNS Hostnames - using internal and external zones

Tags: linux, dns, bind

Looking for the correct or best practice way of doing this.

If you have an external zone called example.com that runs your public mail, web, etc and an internal zone called corp.example.com that runs your databases, intranet, etc.

Do you still assign hostnames as hostname1.example.com and hostname2.example.com and use CNAMES for the corp like hostname2.corp.example.com? Or is it hostname1.example.com and hostname2.corp.example.com both being A records?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using BIND, then views are (IMHO) the clear choice for doing split DNS (internal and external zones, in this case).  I've seen no better explanation than this article:  https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00851/0/Understanding-views-in-BIND-9-by-example.html

EDIT:  Study example #2 in the above link for an idea of what you're aiming for - just replace `trusted` with `internal` and `guests` with `external` and you've got the basic setup done (and probably set recursion to off in the `external` view).  After you understand that, then proceed to the examples for setting up slaves.